# Почему не срабатывает length на массиве?

Tags: javascript

Должно выдать 2

```js
let arr = [];
arr['name'] = 'Имя';
arr['price'] = '1200';

console.log(arr.name);
console.log(arr.price);

console.log((arr).length);
```

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под словом "не срабатывает", и как оно должно "срабатывать"?

Comment: @Igor хочу получить количество элементов в массиве

Comment: В массиве нет ни одного элемента. Вы добавили свойства объекту, а не элементы в массив.

Comment: @Igor нашел решение, оказывается только так можно `Object.keys(arr).length`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [];
arr['name'] = 'Имя';
arr['price'] = '1200';

console.log(arr.name);
console.log(arr.price);

console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);
```

Comment: Вам для этого нет смысла создавать массив, достаточно создать объект. Массив имеет дополнительную специфику, которую вы тут не используете.